# Не подключается к MySQL серверу

Tags: python, mysql

Не могу подключиться к удаленной БД `mysql`.

Ничего не происходит долгое время, далее ошибка:

> CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
>   pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server
>   during query')

Код:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='',
                       user='',
                       passwd='',
                       db='',
                       charset="utf8",
                       port=1500)
cur = conn.cursor()
print("rrghg")

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Все доступы 10 раз уже проверил, все так. Если не прописывать `port=1500`, то ошибка:

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'localhost' ([WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к.
>   конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение)")

Comment: так вы подключаетесь к удаленной БД или к `localhost`??

Comment: удаленной, хост не localhost и не 127.0.0.1

Comment: Как тогда понимать: "Если не прописывать port=1500, то ошибка: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on __'localhost'__"?

Comment: Вот и я про тоже) host='185.11.208.226'

Comment: только что проверил этот host - на нем никто не слушает ни на порту 1500 ни на стандартном для MySQL 3306...

Comment: вы уверены, что на данном хосте стартован MySQL server / daemon ?

Comment: Не знаете как решить вот эту проблему? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/428454

Comment: вам там ответили уже - так делать не стоит. Создавайте полный URL динамически в тот момент когда хотите его использовать...

Comment: Не пойму как это, сделать чтобы сразу прописывалось в момент создания строки, или вообще убрать поле с таким URL, и добавлять только тот который будет использован на сайте? Просто когда до этого добавлялось в ручную, то в каждой записи и такой и такой урл прописывался в бд, теперь хочу сделать импорт, думал это поле важно...